# Javascript ES6: Implementing generator for unfold function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, generator

I'm trying to refactor this code, which defines an `unfold` function and uses it to make the `count` function which fills an array with numbers up to the count. Instead of calling `count(100)` I want to turn count into a generator that can be used by calling `next()` arbitrarily.

```
function unfold (fn, state) {
    return fn( 
        (value, nextState) => {
            return [ value, ...unfold (fn, nextState)]
        },
        ()=>[],
        state
    );
}

function count (max) {
    return unfold(
        (next, done, state)=>{
            return state >= max ?
            done() :
            next(state, state +1)
        }, 
        0
    );
}
```

The flow here is already kind of hard to understand and I'm having a hard time figuring out how the flow of yield statements should work. I want to yield the result array which is line 4 of the `unfold` function `return [ value, ...unfold (fn, nextState)]` but am not sure how to pass that yield all the way up to the count function.

This is what I have so far, but it just returns a generator with a generator inside of it and then ends after a couple `next` calls:

```
function * _unfold (fn, base) {
    yield * fn(
        (value, nextState)=>([ value, ..._unfold (fn, nextState)]),
        base
    )

    return [];
}

function * count (max) {

    yield * _unfold(
        compress,
        0
    );
    return 0;

}

function * compress (next, state) {
    yield next(state, state +1)
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to show you an implementation that is as close to the original unfold implementation in FP as possible. Hopefully from there you can implement it with imperative generators.

Here is a first version of `unfoldr`:

```
unfoldr = f => state => {
  const go = ([x, state_]) =>
    state_ === undefined
      ? []
      : arrCons(x) (go(f(state_)));
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ strictly evaluated

  return go(f(state));
};
```

Unfolding is a process that is inherently infinite, hence you need lazyness to stop it. More precisely you need a function building the structure, which is non-strict in its second argument. `arrCons` could be non-strict in both arguments, because all it does is storing them in a pair-like data type. However, Javascript is strictly evaluated.

Let's pretend we have a function `thunk` that introduces an implicit thunk to Javascript, that is, a nullary function that you can call without parenthesis like a lazy getter on an object. It just takes a normal nullary function and converts it into an implicit one. Here is our updated `unfoldr`:

```
unfoldr = f => state => {
  const go = ([x, state_]) =>
    state_ === undefined
      ? []
      : arrCons(x) (thunk(() => go(f(state_))));

  return go(f(state));
};
```

Now that we mimic non-strict evaluation the expression in the recursive step is evaluated just enough, i.e. reduced to the form `[x, Thunk]`

That is all it takes. Please note that we use `[]` to indicate the base case and thus the end of the unfolding process. We rather should encode this behavior with a tagged union, namely the `Option`/`Maybe` type. But for the sake of simplicity I leave the implementation as it is.

Here is an example of how `unfoldr` is used by defining the Fibonacci sequence:

```
const arrCons = head => tail =>
  [head, tail];

const unfoldr = f => state => {
  const go = ([x, state_]) =>
    state_ === undefined
      ? []
      : arrCons(x) (thunk(() => go(f(state_))));

  return go(f(state));
};

const fibs = unfoldr(
  ([x, y]) => [x, [y, x + y]]) ([0, 1]);

const main = fibs[1] [1] [1] [1] [1] [1] [1] [1] [1] [1]; // [55, Thunk]

main[0]; // 55
```

Here is the full implementation with `thunk` returning a `Proxy`:

```js
const thunk = f =>
  new Proxy(f, new ThunkProxy(f));

const THUNK = "scriptum_thunk";

class ThunkProxy {
  constructor(f) {
    this.memo = undefined;
  }

  apply(g, that, args) {
    if (this.memo === undefined)
      this.memo = g();

    return this.memo(...args);
  }

  defineProperty(g, k, descriptor) { debugger;
    if (this.memo === undefined)
      this.memo = g();

    Object.defineProperty(this.memo, k, descriptor);
    return true;
  }

  get(g, k) {
    if (this.memo === undefined)
      this.memo = g();

    if (k === THUNK)
      return true;

    else if (k === Symbol.toPrimitive)
      return () => this.memo;

    else if (k === "valueOf")
      return () => this.memo;

    else return this.memo[k];
  }

  has(g, k) {
    if (this.memo === undefined)
      this.memo = g();

    return k in this.memo;
  }

  set(g, k, v) {
    if (this.memo === undefined)
      this.memo = g();

    this.memo[k] = v;
    return true;
  }  
}

const arrCons = head => tail =>
  [head, tail];

const arrUnfoldr = f => state => {
  const go = ([x, state_]) =>
    state_ === undefined
      ? []
      : arrCons(x) (thunk(() => go(f(state_))));

  return go(f(state));
};

const fibs = arrUnfoldr(
  ([x, y]) => [x, [y, x + y]]) ([0, 1]);

const main = fibs[1] [1] [1] [1] [1] [1] [1] [1] [1] [1]; // [55, Thunk]

console.log(main[0]);
```